# SQL Server : spatial query result are not showing

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-query

```
SELECT Distinct lu.ObjectID
FROM LAND_USE_EVW as lu
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT LAND_USE_EVW.OBJECTID 
                  FROM LAND_USE_EVW, MUNICIPALITIES_EVW 
                  WHERE LAND_USE_EVW.Shape.STCentroid().STIntersects(MUNICIPALITIES_EVW.shape) = 1
                 )
```

I was trying to get a result that opposite of below

```
select LAND_USE_EVW.OBJECTID 
    from LAND_USE_EVW, MUNICIPALITIES_EVW 
    where    LAND_USE_EVW.Shape.STCentroid().STIntersects(MUNICIPALITIES_EVW.shape) = 1
```

= 0  didn't work therefore I'm trying to come up with other idea.

But result shows nothing. No errors or warning.

Answer (score 0):

found answer

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT LAND_USE_EVW.OBJECTID 
FROM LAND_USE_EVW, MUNICIPALITIES_EVW
```

removing LAND_USE_EVW from FROM LAND_USE_EVW solve the problem